# Calendar API calls begin to produce "SSL peer shut down"

Tags: java, ssl, google-calendar-api, tibco

I have a middleware (developped with Tibco ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks, but I don't think it's very important) that have been working for months, and suddently on 2020-10-17 started to fail on a high number of requests (around 8000) with the error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

Any idea why this error would **suddently start occuring**, and how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Full stacktrace:

```
Job-3158 Error in [BusinessProcesses/AgendasSecurises/Helpers/Gmail/Get Event.process/Get Event] Activity invocation failed at com.tibco.pe.plugin.Activity.postEval(Unknown Source) at com.tibco.pe.plugin.Activity.postEval(Unknown Source) at com.tibco.pe.core.TaskImpl.eval(Unknown Source) at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.a(Unknown Source) at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.k(Unknown Source) at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.a(Unknown Source) at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(Unknown Source) caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228) at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316) at com.tibco.plugin.json.activities.RestActivity.doGet(RestActivity.java:485) at com.tibco.plugin.json.activities.RestActivity.doService(RestActivity.java:473) at com.tibco.plugin.json.activities.RestActivity$1.run(RestActivity.java:418) at com.tibco.pe.util.ThreadPool$ThreadPoolThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:596) at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:399) at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285) ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely that something changed on the server side on the mentioned date.

It could be a change of certificate or some changes that require use of a robust encryption library (for example TLS 1.2 might now be mandatory).

If you are using a recent version of BusinessWorks TLS 1.2 should be enabled by default. If you are using older versions (6.3.x) you may have to edit the bwappnode.tra file with the following :

java.extended.properties=-Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError   -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

You can use the elements from the following TIBCO KB to get more trace and debug your issue:
https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-44615